# Return Exact Match

Tags: excel

I have my pivot table for mentors and mentees matching however, I would like to make matches automatically. For instance, Josie is a mentor and Max is a mentee with same faculty, program, and interests. I'm new to pivot tables but I wanted to know if pivot tables offer an option to show automatic matches or perhaps any suggestion for a formula would also be helpful so that I could use to show Josie and Max as a match.
Note: this is just for example but I will have a bigger data that it is why I want the automatic matches.

**Pivot table**

[image]

**Table:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve is easily possible with pivots. I would suggest you use the org chart concept.

There are plenty of templates online which would allow you to build org chart for example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=adoGOvKTzmM